# Get email address of logged-in user if multiple emails are associated with same account

Tags: reactjs, meteor

Often, users associates multiple email addresses with the same account. But question is, is there any way to know using which email user has logged in into the system?

Note : We are strictly using email for log in and not username.

Mongodb users emails array structure:

```
"emails" : [ 
    {
        "address" : "xyz@abc.com",
        "verified" : true
    },
    {
        "address" : "prq@abc.com",
        "verified" : true
    },
    {
        "address" : "jkl@abc.com",
        "verified" : true
    }
],
```

**Problem statement** - 
One need to order X item, while putting order in system we need email address of logged in user to save in this particular order. So that one can receive notifications related to this particular order.

If we save email address of logged in user to custom database field while logging in it may work but issue is if another user owning same account logs in then second users email will be updated to database and his/her email will get save in order placed by user 1.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you provide a custom form for your users to login? If so, you could check which mail the user has chosen on submit and save this to a custom field (like `lastLogin: { email: 'john@doe.com' }`) using a Meteor method.

Comment: Thank you for reply. Yes I am having custom login form and right now I am doing same as you are suggested but issue is if different user of same account logs in then this field will get updated with user number 2's email address.

Comment: Are you talking about two different users logging in simultaneously ? Cause  Isee you edited your question without commenting my answer which I think fits the problem

Answer (score 0):

The best way to achieve this is to store the last email used for each user while logging in in a custom field in the user model.

Using the [Account.onLogin](https://docs.meteor.com/api/accounts-multi.html#AccountsCommon-onLogin) hook on the server side or your custom login form you can have the user's last email used. Then you should save this email address for each user [in a custom field such as user.lastEmail](https://guide.meteor.com/accounts.html#top-level-fields).

If you do so and need then the lastEmail on the user side, do not forget to publish the custom field to your client such as [described in the documentation](https://guide.meteor.com/accounts.html#publish-custom-data).

Comment: Thank you for answer. But in second paragraph of problem statement it is clearly mentioned about two users logging in simultaneously. And I did not update my problem statement. I have also raise same question in meteor forums https://forums.meteor.com/t/get-email-address-of-logged-in-user-if-multiple-emails-are-associated-with-same-account/45689 you can check timestamp of your answer and question asked.

Comment: The world simultaneously is never used and you edited word 'same' account in your question after my answer... Those info were the most important in your problematic. Why don't you try saving a ip/email pair after each connection and checking against this data when you need to check ? (and when you save a new one you don't erase last one)